# How do I set the display suite default region for newly created fields?

Tags: 9, display-suite, layout-builder

**What needs to be done:**

Newly created fields in any content type should go to the hidden region of the DS Layout.

**Short background:**

In our project we use the Display Suite module, and we have the following custom layout that is used for all the content types.

```
project_layout:
  label: Project layout
  category: Display Suite
  class: '\Drupal\ds\Plugin\DsLayout'
  type: partial
  template: ds_layouts/project_layout/project_layout
  icon: ds_layouts/project_layout/project_layout.png
  regions:
    header:
      label: Header
    left:
      label: Left
    middle:
      label: Middle
    right:
      label: Right
    comments:
      label: Comments
    footer_top:
      label: Footer top
    footer_middle:
      label: Footer middle
    footer_bottom:
      label: Footer bottom
```

`

If a new field is added it always goes to the header region.

What I have tried that does NOT work:

1. Setting

   default_region: hidden

2.Setting

```
default_region: disabled
```

3. Creating new region called test and placing it before  the header region.

In that scenario, the new fields go to the "test" region. In a way this is a workaround, but there should be better solution.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried `ds_hidden` as region_name?

UPDATE, or `none` (still guessing).

Comment: I tried adding 
default_region: ds_hidden , but it doesnt work

Comment: Sorry - bad guess then..